# Why does a car's price decrease after upgrades?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought a Zentorno, for ~750k and I have upgraded it for around a couple of hundred thousand, and yet it's sell prize at Los Santos Customs is only 529k?!

Why has this happened? It makes no sense.

Comment: Everyone knows a car loses 20% of its value when you take it on a crime spree.

Comment: Sale value on your used Zentorno is never going to be the same as you bought it for. I don't remember the exact numbers, but I think it sells for 50% of the purchase value and the upgrade prices are calculated differently. You will never be able to make back the money you spent buying a car by selling it.

Comment: You can't by a brand new car in real life for "x" dollars and sell it back used for the same amount, same logic applies in GTA.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't decrease after upgrades, per se, but it always loses half its value from whatever you do. For instance: if you purchase a Zentorno for $750,000 and take it STRAIGHT to Los Santos Customs you will only be able to sell it for half of its purchased value ($375,000).

If you then add a spoiler for $1000, and level 1 suspension for $2000, you will have increased your cars value by $1500 despite spending $3000 on it. Your car will now be worth $376,500).

However, because you can only have one spoiler, and one suspension, along with one of everything else, if you further upgrade your car with level 4 suspension which costs you $10,000, your car will now be worth $380,500. Even though you spent $10,000, because you *replaced* the suspension on your car, you no longer get the $1000 from the level 1 suspension.